# Bigcommerce: how can I make sure the JWT token sent to my system is the correct one for the user

Tags: jwt, bigcommerce

I have a requirement to show some data in the Bigcommerce store for our customers.

These data should be visible only for logged in users.
To show these data in bigcommerce, Rest API call has to be made from Bigcommerce frontend to our Server.

I have learned from Bigcommerce that I can add Javascript code to get the JWT token for the logged in user.
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/customers/current-customer-api

I can send the JWT token from Bigcommerce frontend to my server.

The question is starting from my server how can I make sure the token is valid.

Is there any API in bigcommerce which allow me to send the JWT and reply that the token is valid and it's safe to send your sensitive data to the customer?
Thanks.

Comment: Depends on how the token was created. You need the corresponding key `JWK`, and depending what language you're using a JWT lib to decode https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt It can be created using a secret string or using a private key.

Comment: @Lex Thanks for your help. I am using Python3 in my server. but the JWT token will be created in Bigcommerce. My Javascript code in the frontend is just getting the JWT token from Bigcommerce . so I don't create the token. from my server I need to validate the token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JWT sent from BigCommerce will be signed with your app's Client Secret. When you decode the token on your server (you can use one of the Python client libraries on https://jwt.io/), the Client Secret match is the indication that the JWT is authentic and came from BigCommerce.